# Printful API Key on Python script

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I will use the Printfull API, but I can't find on way to test the API Key, on my script. Some of you can tell me how is the best way to do this? Thank you. Flavio

```py
import json
import requests

key = ('random:key')
r = requests.get('https://api.printful.com/sync/products')
packages_json = r.key.json()

print(packages_json)
```

Comment: Is your question how to make a request using the API key?

Comment: By the way if that is your API key your reallllllly should not post that on here because it gives every access to your account!

Comment: thank you, but this is only a test with a test product, I will generate another one when I understand how this work.

Comment: Is your question how to make a request using the API key? Exactly.

Comment: I add a simple code that could work. If it doesn't please let me know and tell me what error arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization to Printful API would look something like this:

```
import base64

key = 'random:key'
key = base64.b64encode(bytes(key, 'utf-8'))
keyDecoded = key.decode('ascii')
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + keyDecoded}
requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this with Oauth2.